# div created by javascript not accepting css data inputted through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i created the div 'egg' using javascript, and then tried styling it using jquery. However, this did not work. Can somebody please explain why

```
egg = document.createElement('div');
$('#egg').css('background-color', 'blue');
$('#egg').css('height', '200px');
$('#egg').css('width', '200px');
$('#egg').css('position','absolute');
$('#egg').css('top','500px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#egg')` will try to find element having id as `egg` in the DOM but you have not appended `egg` element in the DOM yet.

Also note you have not specified `id` attribute to the created element.

Try this:

```js
var egg = document.createElement('div');
egg.setAttribute('id', 'egg');
document.body.appendChild(egg);
$('#egg').css('background-color', 'blue');
$('#egg').css('height', '200px');
$('#egg').css('width', '200px');
$('#egg').css('position', 'absolute');
$('#egg').css('top', '500px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var egg = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(egg)
egg.id = "egg";
$("#egg").css('height',200);
```